# I need an algorithm to measure content quality

Tags: algorithm, wordpress, plugins

is there an algorithm to measure the content quality ? http://www.the-top-tens.com/ in top tens when you vote an item, there is a comment box appearing and when you start writing why you vote this item, it comments automatically about what you write. I am curious about how they do it?

I will adopt this algorithm to wordpress. I think it will be perfect for wordpress users.

Comment: The best known such algorithm lives in the human brain but even that is fallible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a quick check of the site you linked to. Their algorithm appears to boil down to "longer comment == higher quality". Not exactly a sophisticated algorithm. For example, this

```
asklfklasf kajslkjf akjs flkajsfklajs fkjaskfj aklsjf kajsfk ajskfj alksjf aklsjfkl asfjaklsjf
```

was given their top quality rating...

Some ideas to make this better:

- Check spelling (mispelled words reduce quality)
- Check for swear words and other profanity.
- Length is probably important, but I wouldn't put much weight on it.
- Grammar would be good to check, although difficult.
- Running a spam filter over it would be a good first step.

Those are just some ideas. For the spelling and profanity, just check each words against a dictionary. Grammar would be more difficult as you start to move into natural language processing, which is a very deep area of research.